# Format Structure for StringBuilder

Tags: c#, formatting, stringbuilder

```
private void add_value_to_row(client_file client_file, ref StringBuilder OutputCustomer, String value)
{
   if (client_file.output_format == "txt") 
      if (value = "the first value in add_value_to_row")
         OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("{0}", value); 
      else if (value = "every other value in add_value_to_row")  
         OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("\t{0}", value);
}
```

I have a function written above that takes inputs from "x" and create data rows in .txt format according to the code below. I was wondering how I could write the nested if statements so that it performed what is written in quotes? The final output according to the data below should output `OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", x.url, x.company, x.Country, x.vendor, x.product);`

```
OutputCustomer = new StringBuilder();

add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.url);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.company);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.Country);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.vendor);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.product);
```

Comment: it's still unclear as what you are exactly asking here?

Comment: It's hard to understand the intent of "the first value add_value_to_row", because `add_value_to_row` appears to be a method rather than a collection. Are you saying that you want the method to guess which property you passed it? By the way, `StringBuilder` is a class, not a struct. No need to pass by `ref`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you adding the items one by one? Give your object to the method and let it decide.

```
private void add_value_to_row(client_file client_file, ref StringBuilder OutputCustomer, YourType value)
{
   if (client_file.output_format == "txt") 

     OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
     value.url,value.company,value.Country,value.vendor,value.product); 

}
```

And call it like this

```
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x);
```

Otherwise you have to give a bool or int in the methods signiture

**Update**

If you really want to have your method the way it is you need a boolean in the signiture

```
private void add_value_to_row(client_file client_file, ref StringBuilder OutputCustomer, String value, bool isFirst=false)
{
   if (client_file.output_format == "txt") 
      if (isFirst)
         OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("{0}", value); 
      else  
         OutputCustomer.AppendFormat("\t{0}", value);
}
```

And call it like this

```
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.url, true);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.company);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.Country);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.vendor);
add_value_to_row(clientInfo.cf, ref OutputCustomer, x.product);
```

Also pay attention that you can have it as an optional parameter so you don't need to write it everytime

Comment: I only wrote 5 items to make the example concise, but there's actually a lot more in the actual code. I just needed to write the if statements so that the first item is formatted {0} and then rest are \t{0}

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @LucasHan you are welcome. :) Also don't forget to mark as answer and up vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a tab-delimited output row. A much easier way to do it would be:

```
string outputCustomer = string.Join("\t", new {x.url, x.company, x.Country, x.vendor, x.product});
```

See [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx).